# How long does it take to recharge the Disruptor to detonate proximity mines?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

After detonating 2 proximity mines in order, the Disruptor cannot be used. I guess that some time must pass for recharging until I can re-use it.

How long does it take to recharge the Disruptor?

Comment: While I answered below, I'm pretty sure that no situations require more than two mines to be detonated at once.  What brought this question on?  Are you trying to solve a riddler puzzle?  If so, keep in mind that you only need to detonate mines you walk directly over.  Find the path that crosses the least mines, and you shouldn't need to detonate more than two of them.

Comment: Also, in a maze, you can walk through a mine, and you can survive two mines if you're fully upgraded, so even if you only detonate one of the right ones, you can survive walking through another both ways.

Comment: I saw a maze near the dock with lots of mines in it, and it brought this question on. I made it through the mines after detonating two mines, though.

Comment: north of the steel mill, to the west of that entrance, there is a straight through maze situation in cages that requires 4 disruptions. you can do it with 2 + fast walk if you are fully charged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes roughly a minute for the disruptor's cooldown to allow you to detonate another mine.

Comment: If you are in (Riddler) challenge, it doesn't recharge at all. You may only use the disruptor two times to solve those riddles.